# BeautifulSoup won't parse Article element

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm working on parsing [this](https://www.arsenal.com/fixtures) web page.

I've got `table = soup.find("div",{"class","accordions"})` to get just the fixtures list (and nothing else) however now I'm trying to loop through each match one at a time. It looks like each match starts with an article element tag `<article role="article" about="/fixture/arsenal/2018-apr-01/stoke-city">`

However for some reason when I try to use  `matches = table.findAll("article",{"role","article"})`

and then print the length of matches, I get 0.

I've also tried to say `matches = table.findAll("article",{"about","/fixture/arsenal"})` but get the same issue.

Is BeautifulSoup unable to parse  tags, or am I just using it wrong?

Comment: You need to pass a dictionary, not a set. Just replace the comma `,` with a colon `:` and it'll work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
matches = table.findAll('article', attrs={'role': 'article'})
```

Comment: That looks like it did it, thanks. I didn't realize that it would be attributes instead of just a normal findAll tag.

Answer (score 0):

the reason is that findAll is searching for tag name. refer to [bs4 docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the attributes as a dictionary. There are three ways in which you can get the data you want.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.arsenal.com/fixtures')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

matches = soup.find_all('article', {'role': 'article'})
print(len(matches))
# 16
```

Or, this is also the same:

```
matches = soup.find_all('article', role='article')
```

But, both these methods give some extra article tags that don't have the `Arsernal` fixtures. So, if you want to find them using `/fixture/arsenal` you can use [CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors). (Using `find_all` won't work, as you need a partial match)

```
matches = soup.select('article[about^=/fixture/arsenal]')
print(len(matches))
# 13
```

Also, have a look at [the keyword arguments](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments). It'll help you get what you want.